# Dividing a column into N equal groups by value

Tags: excel

Say I have a column with values:

```
23
24
25
66
67
84
81
85
```

I want to divide this into N groups, say N right now is 4.

```
23,1
24,1
25,2
66,2
67,3
84,3
81,4
85,4
```

I actually need to divide around 30k sorted values into groups 1 to 99; each with equal number of elements.

Any quick way to do this in Excel?

Comment: do you need the groups 1 next to eachother or is 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 also good?

Answer (score 3):

With data in column **A,** in **B1** enter:

```
=A1 & "," & ROUNDUP(ROW()/(COUNT(A:A)/4),0)
```

and copy down.  For example:

.

[image: demo]

Change the **4** in the formula to vary the number of groups.

Answer (score 3):

I use this trick for equal data bucketing. Suppose you have data in `A1:A8` range. Put this formula in B1:

```
=MAX( ROUNDUP( PERCENTRANK($A$1:$A$8, A1) *4, 0),1)
```

[image]

Fill down the formula all across B column and you are done. The formula divides the range into 4 equal buckets and it returns the bucket number which the cell A1 falls into. The first bucket contains the lowest 25% of values.

Adjust the number of buckets according to thy wish:

```
=MAX(ROUNDUP(PERCENTRANK([Range],[OneCellOfTheRange]) *[NumberOfBuckets],0),1)
```

The number of observation in each bucket will be equal or almost equal. For example if you have a 100 observations and you want to split it into 3 buckets then the buckets will contain 33, 33, 34 observations. So almost equal. You do not have to worry about that - the formula works that out for you.

Comment: What if the cell values is in text?

Comment: How about checking and seeing? :-)

Comment: how about answering the question? using text values returns error

Answer (score 0):

if this is in column A

- row 1
- row 2
- row 3
- row 4
- row 5

place formula in column B

```
=MOD(ROW(); 4)+1
```

this result in

- row 1,   2
- row 2,   3
- row 3,   4
- row 4,   1
- row 2,   2

Comment: Your solution does not return expected results. You missed the point.